# Entity Framework Migrations don't include DefaultValue data annotation (EF5RC)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-5

I have a class that looks like this:

```
[Table("Subscribers", Schema = "gligoran")]
public class Subscriber
{
    [Key]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

When creating a migration to include this class I get:

```
public partial class AddSubscriberClass : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "gligoran.Subscribers",
            c => new
                {
                    Email = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Enabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Email);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("gligoran.Subscribers");
    }
}
```

I'd like the `Enabled` line to look like this:

```
Enabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValue: true),
```

Of course I can do this myself, but I'm just asking if there's a way to make Entity Framework do it automatically.

I'm using the latest Entity Framework 5 RC (5.0.0-rc.net40).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EF doesn't use `DefaultValue` attribute at all = it is not part of the model so migrations don't see it. You can propose support of this annotation on [Data UserVoice](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions).

Comment: I guess manually is the only was. Thanks for the UserVoice link, though. I have a couple of ideas for them.

Comment: Actually MS today released [EF as open source](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/) so you can even try it yourselves ;)

Comment: Nice! I was searching for it the other day and came to the conclusion that it's not open. I like the new(ish) Microsoft open policy.

Comment: Here's an existing [User Voice suggestion for this feature](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2929682-support-database-default-values-in-code-first).

Answer (score 7):

As an Extra to Ladislav's Comment. Which is correct. you cant do it in the model. IF you wanted to use code based migrations.  Ie using PM commandlet Add-Migration / Update Database,   then this approach introduces a generated class into the process.  Then you can have defaults .  See the classes that Derive from DBMigrations.  see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.addcolumn%28v=vs.103%29.aspx 
You can specific Column builder Lamda expressions. This allows defaults.

```
namespace MigrationsDemo.Migrations
{
  using System;
  using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

public partial class SomeClassThatisATable : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("MyTable", "MyColumn", c => c.String( defaultvalue:"Mydefault"  ));
    }
```