# EntityFramework Code First FluentAPI DefaultValue in EF6.X

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

How can I set the default value using EntityFramework Code First FluentAPI for bool property?

Something like:

```
Property(l => l.PropertyFlag).HasColumnType("bit").DefaultValue(1);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can set a default value constraint with Entity Framework 6 Code First?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136504/how-can-set-a-default-value-constraint-with-entity-framework-6-code-first)

Comment: There should be some kind of solution for this issue, not just simple "No". I am talking all possible solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't realised that. I thought you were looking for how to set the default value using EntityFramework Code First FluentAPI for bool property. How foolish of me ;-)

Answer (score 31):

Good news, code first now supports this. In the "Up()" method of the generated migration, specify a default with the following syntax:

```
AddColumn("[table name]", "[column name]", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValue: false));
```

[MSDN for "AddColumn" method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.addcolumn%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Comment: @joelmdev Added a link to MSDN documentation

Comment: This is only an Up migration.  The OP is asking for how to set defaults at time of insert.  Behind-the-scenes, EF maps every property in the POCO into the Insert statement as a NULL if the C# property is null.  For value types, it inserts the value types default value.  Useful info, though!

Comment: The downside is that you have to remember to re-add this peice of code if you re-scafold your migration. Hopefully they will support this function in Fluent Api soon.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure about a fluent way, but you can simply set the property in a parameterless constructor...

```
public class MyTable
{
    public MyTable()
    {
        CanSetDefault = true;
    }

    public bool CanSetDefault {get; set; }
}
```

**Update**

A quick google suggests it is not possible using the fluent api...
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ad854e28-02f5-451b-9000-c8bcb1355d0b/codefirst-ctp5-and-default-values?forum=adonetefx

Comment: Good suggestion, but doesn't work for DateTime.Now which is used for CreatedOn fields, as you will have clock drift from the time the class instance is constructed to when it is inserted.  This would lead to some hard-to-debug code based on audit logs.

Comment: This is now being worked on for EF7 and available in pre-release https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2929682-support-database-default-values-in-code-first

Comment: This only works for entries added with this. If you have existing entries, and you are adding a column to your schema, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Another option here is to override the default **SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator** class with your own. You can then inject certain things you want to happen in the Generate method (for example, default values). The nice things with this is that you can also use this in other applications as it is pretty generic. [Here](https://andy.mehalick.com/2014/02/06/ef6-adding-a-created-datetime-column-automatically-with-code-first-migrations/) is a good explanation on it.

```
 internal class CustomSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
{

    protected override void Generate(AddColumnOperation addColumnOperation)
    {
        SetCreatedUtcColumn(addColumnOperation.Column);

        base.Generate(addColumnOperation);
    }

    protected override void Generate(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation)
    {
        SetCreatedUtcColumn(createTableOperation.Columns);

        base.Generate(createTableOperation);
    }


    private static void SetCreatedUtcColumn(IEnumerable<ColumnModel> columns)
    {
        foreach (var columnModel in columns)
        {
            SetCreatedUtcColumn(columnModel);
        }
    }

    private static void SetCreatedUtcColumn(PropertyModel column)
    {
        if (column.Name == "CreatedUtc")
        {
            column.DefaultValueSql = "GETUTCDATE()";
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Full explanation: https://andy.mehalick.com/2014/02/06/ef6-adding-a-created-datetime-column-automatically-with-code-first-migrations/

Answer (score 0):

Since EF doesn't have the functions I need, such as default values and unique key as foreign keys, we have to change the ORM from EF to NHibernate. It seems to me that NHibernate has more functions than EF 6.X.