# Setting default value in MVC database first

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi is there a cleaner way to set default value in database first other than initialize in the partial class like below?

```
[MetadataType(typeof(PersonAttribute))]
public partial class person {
    public person() {
        isMale = true;
    }
}


public class PersonAttribute
{
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the news title.")]
    public string UserTitle { get; set; }
    public bool isMale { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: you can specify in migration code like : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136504/how-can-set-a-default-value-constraint-with-entity-framework-6-code-first

Comment: Hi,i am using Database first method instead. thanks

Comment: I have seen this link this link http://dotnet-concept.com/Tips/2016/1/5798842/Inserting-default-values-in-database-while-inserting-record-in-Entity-Framework that states:

Step 1: Open EDMX file and locate your table in that file.

Step 2: Select the property name. Right click and click on property.

Step 3: You will find a property named as StoreGeneratedPattern with value set as None.

Step 4: Set StoreGeneratedPattern = "Computed".

Now you can insert default values using EF.

I have no idea if this works or not though.

Comment: The other thing to check is... To give a default value the property must be non-nullable otherwise you will need to set the default value inside the constructor.

Comment: no luck with the method above.i tried to set the value in database then set to Computed doesnt work. so i set the default value in dataAnnotation also. also no luck when i set default value on both

Comment: Hi sorry, i tested again. it works after i insert to database.Previously i set a break point during processing and didnt show up. thanks. solved.