# Passing Query String Values to a View Model in Asp.net MVC App

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I pass query string values to a view model parameter that has default values in ASP.net MVC app?

I tried so but didn't succeed;

```
public ActionResult Index(MyAnotherVM filter){
  // filter.p doesn't set passed value and it equals to 1
}

public class MyAnotherVM {
 public int p { get { return 1; } set { } }
 // or
 public int p=1;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I found an answer about using constructor. I tried and solved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23823151/547271

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of TempData

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FillStudent(Student student1)
{
    TempData["student"]= new Student();
    return RedirectToAction("GetStudent","Student");
    }

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetStudent(Student passedStd)
{
    Student std=(Student)TempData["student"];
    return View();
}
```

### Approach 2:

using Query string data passed

Or you can frame it with the help of query strings like

```
return RedirectToAction("GetStudent","Student", new {Name="John",             Class="clsz"});
```

**This will generate a GET Request like**

```
Student/GetStudent?Name=John & Class=clsz
```

But make sure you have [HttpGet] since RedirectToAction will issue GET Request(302)